# Vue.JS Checking if the user came from our domain

Tags: c#, vue.js

I would like the user to be able to enter the link from the email, go through the authorization process and redirect it to the path from the email. I can't use the back method and go because if the user enters the login path directly after each login it will go back to the previous page. Do you have any ideas or solutions to my problem?

Comment: Your question is, at best, very unclear. You tagged the question [c#], so possibly you are on Asp.Net Core or similar on the server side. What you probably want to do, if that is the case, is redirect the user to the login page but with an extra param "redirectUrl" or similar. You can search for "Asp.Net Core login redirect". If this is not enough, please at least take the time to better explain your problem: "the email" doesn't really explain what kind of e-mail, link, and flow you're trying to build.

Comment: My point is to check in vue if the user came from our website before the login view, for example localhost:8080/ if so, go back to the previous page. If it came from another domain, redirect to the home page.

Comment: IMHO, Vue is the wrong place to check this kind of things. The server side knows if the user is logged or not. And the server side can respond with appropriate status codes and redirects. Login is best handled by the server, not by the client, which probably does not have the information to decide how it should behave.

Comment: I check whether the user is logged in or not. now my problem is to determine what domain the client came from. If from ours, go back to the previous page, if not, redirect to the main page.

Comment: But you don't know that, because the referrer is lost. You _could_ look at the navigation history, but I don't know if it could work (I don't know the details of the security on that). What the server should do, is deny the opening of the page to unknown users, and redirect ALL of them to the login page. Maybe there are JS only solutions, but I don't think you have all the necessary bits you need to solve the problem on the client side.